# ASCII key code of Functions key in Objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsstring, ascii

I am developing an application in which i need ASCII code. I know i can get through string function `characterAtIndex` but my task is to get ASCII of functions keys like f1 and f2 I added these button via code because as far as i know that there is no functions key mentioned in iPhone keyboard. 
So should i add also manually their ASCII keys like f1 has 112 or any other approach. If anyone has better idea please share with me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't believe the ASCII set contains function keys, even in the extended ASCII table.  DEC 112 is lowercase p.

Comment: @MrSlayer read this link [http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/464-keyboard-event-character-values-for-the-lower-ascii-character-set/]

Comment: Thanks, @josh.  Event KeyCodes are not the same as ASCII codes.

Comment: hmmm, but slayer i need exactly this(Event key code), is this possible?

Comment: On iOS (as you've tagged this question)? No, as there aren't any hardware keys to be assigned key codes!

Comment: Yeah, I've never seen function keys on an iPhone.  Are you talking about OS X instead?